# Absolute maximum for $f(x,y) = 4x^2 + 5y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Suppose you have a region $R$ that satisfies $4x^2+y^2\leq 4$ What is the absolute maximum of the function $f(x,y) = 4x^2 + 5y$ on $R$?

The correct answer is $10$

First, I calculated the critical points in $R$:

$$f_x = 8x$$
$$8x= 0$$
$$x=0$$

$$f_y = 5$$
$$5 \ne  0$$

Given the fact that there are no points where both $f_x$ and $f_y$ equal $0$, doesn't that mean there are no critical points in $R$, indicating no maximum value? I don't know if I have to check the boundary in this case, since the region is circular? I am not allowed to use Lagrange Multipliers.

Any insight into how to solve these types of problems would help.

Comment: On the boundary substitute $x^2$ from the equation of the boundary into $f(x,y)$ and find and minimise over $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x)=x$ also has an absolute maximum on $[-1,1]$, even though there is no point at which $f'(x)=0$.

Remember, the zeroes of the partial derivatives only give you candidates for the critical points in the **interior** of the domain of $f$. On the border (where a maximum can also be reached sometimes), you can use [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) to calculate the max.

Alternatively, your particular function is fairly simple, so you can do without Lagrange. You have, on the border, $4x^2+y^2=4$, which means you can express $x^2$ as a funciton of $y$, and insert that into $f(x,y)$ to get a function of only $y$, and you can calculate the maximum of $f$ on the border quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

When the function is defined by a simple expression ad-hoc methods are recommended. You can find the maximum  without using any theorems. $f(x,y) \leq 5y+4-y^{2}$ and $y$ is subject to the condition $-2\leq y \leq 2$. This gives $f(x,y)\leq 10$ and this value is attained when $x=0,y=2$.

Answer (score 1):

You proved that there are no critical points in the interior of $R$. In order to see what happens at the boundary of $R$, you can use the method of Lagrange multipliers, which leads you to the system:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}8x=8\lambda x\\5=8\lambda y\\4x^2+y^2=4.\end{array}\right.$$

---

Otherwise, you can reduce this to a $1$-dimensional problem: find the maximum of$$(4\cos\theta)^2+5\times4\sin\theta,$$with $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. It is perhaps better to keep in mind that $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$.

Comment: I am expected to solve it w/o Lagrange. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Answer (score 0):

We have: $4x^2 + 5y \le 4-y^2+5y =10 -y^2+5y-6=10 -(y-2)(y-3)\le 10$ since $y \le 2$.